# ODE: proving independent solutions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ and $y_1(x),y_2(x)$ are two independent solutions of this ODE.
How can i prove that $u_1(x)=Ay_1(x)+By_2(x)$, $u_2(x)=Cy_1(x)+Dy_2(x)$
are also two independent solutions if and only if $AD\neq BC$?

Comment: Hi. Are you familiar with the Wronskian $x\mapsto W(x)\underset{\text{def}}{=}\det\begin{pmatrix}y_1(x)&y_2(x)\\ y_1'(x)&y_2'(x)\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: yes! i forgot about it, been a while since i've touched ODEs  ty

Answer (score 1):

Let's remind that two solutions $y_1,y_2$ of an ODE $$(E) : y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$ on an interval $I$ are linearly independant if and only if their wronskian does not vanish on $I$.

However, if we write $x\mapsto W(u,v)(x)\underset{\text{def}}{=}\det\begin{pmatrix}u(x)&v(x)\\ u'(x)&v'(x)\end{pmatrix}$ the wronskian of a familly of two solution $(u,v)$ then :
$$\begin{align*}\forall x\in I, \quad W(Ay_1+By_2, Cy_1+Dy_2)(x)&  = \det\begin{pmatrix}Ay_1(x)+By_2(x)&Cy_1(x)+Dy_2(x)\\ Ay_1'(x)+By_2'(x)&Cy_1'(x)+Dy_2'(x)\end{pmatrix} \\ 
& = \det\left[\begin{pmatrix}y_1(x)&y_2(x)\\ y_1'(x)&y_2'(x)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A & C \\ B&D \end{pmatrix} \right] \\
& = \det\begin{pmatrix}y_1(x)&y_2(x)\\ y_1'(x)&y_2'(x)\end{pmatrix} \times \det\begin{pmatrix}A & C \\ B&D \end{pmatrix} \\
& = W(y_1,y_2)(x)\times (AD-BC)
\end{align*}$$

Since $y_1,y_2$ are linearly independant solutions of $(E)$ on $I$, $W(y_1,y_2)$ does not vanish on $I$. Thus, $W(Ay_1+By_2, Cy_1+Dy_2)$ vanishes on $I$ if and only if $AD-BC=0$ meaning that the family $(Ay_1+By_2, Cy_1+Dy_2)$ is linearly independant  if and only if $AD-BC\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to the given ODE "live" as vectors inside a vector space known as the solution space. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are given as linearly independent solutions, and thus are basis vectors for the solution space. We can construct solutions (vectors) from the solution space by taking linear combinations of $y_1$ and $y_2$. This is precisely what $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ are.

We want $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ to be linearly independent, otherwise when normalized, they would be equivalent. The two vectors $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$ are linearly independent if the only numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfying $ 
\alpha{u_1(x)}+\beta{u_2(x)}=0 $ are $ \alpha=\beta=0 $. Let $u_1(x)=\begin{pmatrix}Ay_1 \\ By_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $u_2(x)=\begin{pmatrix} Cy_1 \\ Dy_2 \end{pmatrix}$. $\alpha{u_1(x)}+\beta{u_2(x)}=0$ can equivalently be written as: $ \alpha \begin{pmatrix}Ay_1 \\ By_2 \end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix} Cy_1 \\ Dy_2 \end{pmatrix} = \vec{0} = \begin{pmatrix} 
Ay_1 & Cy_1 \\ By_2 & Dy_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} $. We now must show that $ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} = \vec{0}$. This will happen when $ \begin{vmatrix} Ay_1 & Cy_1 \\ By_2 & Dy_2 \end{vmatrix} \neq 0$. $$ \begin{vmatrix} Ay_1 & Cy_1 \\ By_2 & Dy_2 \end{vmatrix} = (AD-BC)y_1y_2 \neq 0 \\ AD \neq BC$$